# How can I pass a dataframe column to a user-defined function as an argument?

Tags: r

What I am trying to do is set up a basic user-defined function for a class that will create a boxplot for a predictor variable against a target variable. This is my code:

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=target, y=predictor)) + geom_boxplot(
  aes(col=target), notch=TRUE)}
#Below is how I'm calling the function
BoxplotPredictorOnTarget(df$target, df$predictor)
```

My question is, is there a more elegant way that I can use dataframe column names as my arguments in the call to the function? It would be nice to be able to add names to the x and y axes of the resulting boxplots based on the same arguments. I'm also just confused about how this works. When I make the function call and just put the column names in double quotes, without using the dataframe variable name and "$" operator, it returns a boxplot that is just a straight line and for which the axes don't make any sense, they're just the column names. I'm confused why using the strings of the column names as an argument doesn't work, when they get inserted into the function it should be the same as if I were to just write the column names in, right?

Answer (score 2):

We can convert the column name string to a symbol and evaluate

```
library(ggplot2)  
BoxplotPredictorOnTarget <- function(df, target, predictor) {

    ggplot(data = df, aes(x= !! rlang::ensym(target),
              y= !! rlang::ensym(predictor))) +
         geom_boxplot(aes(col= !! rlang::ensym(target)), notch=TRUE)
   }
```

then call as

```
BoxplotPredictorOnTarget(df, 'target', 'predictor')
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
BoxplotPredictorOnTarget(iris, 'Species', 'Sepal.Length')
```

-output

[image]